# Handle both React.KeyboardEvent or React.MouseEvent in one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I'm trying to get a function to handle both click and keyboard events as I'm trying to make my web app keyboard accessible.  When I use the `|` symbol for the type I get an error:

```
Property 'key' does not exist on type 'KeyboardEvent<Element> | MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>'.
  Property 'key' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>'.
```

My function currently:

```
const handleChange = (e: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent): void => {
  if (e.type !== 'mousedown' || e.key !== ' ') return;

  ...other stuff...
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to get this working as expected?  I could just write to separate functions, but I thought that it would be nice to keep it in one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Type Assertion to do this (https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion):

```
const handleChange = (e: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent): void => {
  if (e.type !== 'mousedown' || (e as React.KeyboardEvent).key !== ' ') return;

  ...other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Although this is a useful answer, i've been advised to avoid type assertions at my company in favour of using type guards.

Answer (score 3):

Your function doesn't know if `e` is a `KeyboardEvent` or a `MouseEvent`. You'll need to implement a [Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to let your block of code know if it is dealing with a `KeyboardEvent`.

```
import React from 'react'

/** ChangeEvent represents either a KeyboardEvent or a MouseEvent */
type ChangeEvent = React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent

/** Type-guard to check if event is a KeyboardEvent */
const isKeyboardEvent = (e: ChangeEvent): e is React.KeyboardEvent => {
    return (e as React.KeyboardEvent).getModifierState !== undefined
}

const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent): void => {
    if (isKeyboardEvent(e)) {
        // Do keyboard stuff here
        if (e.type !== 'mousedown' || e.key !== ' ') return;
    }
}
```

In this case, I'm checking to see if the event has the function `getModifierState` defined, as that function should only be defined for `KeyboardEvent` and not for `MouseEvent`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSB6AKirgGEALFAOwHMkBRANyWfiLBEAzrxhC4SYDAZIocFHADSSAJ4AjCCigATbqLjR5cALIQAriL184VCqRgqwSekzace1gLyJiMAHTK6po6VvAAPj7o-qYW7qLk1LQAKo5IALSsZlracDAQcGgyaADWcMCYEh7wwOIKgRrZoTZ2aBDMQtVC9cG6VXDeABRIAFwuLOyhAJSjzjWRGAGqDSF9ngB8cADepHC7cEQwZlDMcEPy4shRi0GNVZN+7DCm2uXAsgDKMCgwzgCEnt4zMxtEhMMBmEhtKQAL7kVrteCubQAGyQjHGzkGIzGbimoy4EGAOXWWx2e3Kpxq3VuoiGk0mpL2TLgFAocAAIvliksenAOmZMBUZEQycyyhUhn4HE44P9vPgQOYRNoIAB3Zj4OBhCJIPzclSygEEAgMg5HZgAblFcFh0KAA)

Comment: There's nothing specific to if it's a keyboard event... I want to do the same logic if it's a keyboard event or a mouse event one of which is a mouse down and the other of which is a spacebar press.

Comment: The `key` property is specific to the `KeyboardEvent`, which is why you are getting the error message. So you could adapt your code to this: `if (e.type !== 'mousedown' || (isKeyboardEvent(e) && e.key !== ' '))`. You could also just use the `// @ts-ignore` comment to skip type-checking on that line, but that's not something that I like to do often

Comment: This doesn't work for me because getModifierState() exists on all React synthetic events.  The code above always sets the event to KeyboardEvent