# To use two event handlers simultaneously in a typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```js
  const handleStart = (e: React.MouseEvent | React.TouchEvent) => {
    if (!ref.current) return;
    setStartX(e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX);
  };
```

```
<ul ref={ulRef}>
  onMouseDown={handleStart}
  onTouchStart={handleStart}
</ul>
```

The code above is the code created to use both mouse and touch events in React at the same time.
There is a type error, what should I do?

### error message

TS2345: Argument of type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> | TouchEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> & TouchEvent'.
Type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> & TouchEvent'.
Type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>' is missing the following properties from type 'TouchEvent': changedTouches, targetTouches, touches

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65928720/handle-both-react-keyboardevent-or-react-mouseevent-in-one-function? (btw, there should be multiple type errors in those snippets)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it will work

```
<ul
  ref={ulRef}
  onMouseDown={(e) => handleStart(e)}
  onTouchStart={(e) => handleStart(e)}
></ul>
```